# Trying to get jCarousel to fetch new set of records on click of Next button

Tags: jquery

I've been trying for the last 2 days to get this thing to call my
getJSON and fetch a new set of records based on the carousel.last
value when you click the next button.  It loads 3 pictures on start up
just fine but the next button is not enabled because I only have 3
loaded and there are no more lingering in the queue.  I don't want any
lingering.

Check out this example, this is what I'm trying to do but instead
fetch the new set of images with my getJSON method:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_flickr_api.html

So here is my code but it's not working meaning I load 3 images and
the next button is not enabled.  Even when I load 4 images (to get the
next button to be clickable because I've loaded 4 images and it knows
there's another one in addition to the 3), it doesn't go and fetch a
new set of 3 images:

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></
script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js" type="text/
javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/
jquery.jcarousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/skin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback
    });

});

function decode(s)
{
    return s.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
            .replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
            .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
            .replace(/&gt;/g, ">");

};

function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state) {

    carousel.lock();

        //for (var i = carousel.first; i <= carousel.last; i++) {
            mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, carousel.first,
carousel.last);
        //}

};

function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last) {
    // Unlock
    carousel.unlock();

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:59396/xxx/xxxHandler.ashx?
action=carouselproducts&setsize=3" + "&cfirst=" + carousel.first +
"&clast=" + carousel.last,
        function(data) {
            carousel.size(data.length);
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                carousel.add(i, decode(item.ImageTag));
                if (i == 3) return false;
            });
        });

};

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-ie7">
                <!-- this will be dynamically populated -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what else to try here or how to get that working like the
example.  And I don't think I need all that paging logic because I'm
not using Flickr, and I want to just base the next set to fetch based
on the first and last index of the carousel by calling my getJSON on click of next or previous buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and ran it in FF4 and IE9. Next button is enabled and I even see ajax calls being made when I click the next icon. Is your problem browser specific?

[image]